# How can I make bootable macOS High Sierra without the HighSierra App from App Store

Tags: macos, install, high-sierra

I have downloaded a genuine copy of macOS High Sierra from a website and after I opened it I can see many part files (like part 1, part 2 ...). How can I install macOS from these part files? How can I make a bootable out of it?

Comment: It sounds like you've downloaded a sketchy macOS installer from a sketchy source. Why not just go to the app store and download the real thing from a reputable source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the installer came in archive parts. You can use [The Unarchiver from the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) to extract the installer from the archive. Be sure to select **part1** when extracting. Also remember, downloading macOS from 3rd party websites might be dangerous as they might be modified.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title. You **can** create a bootable MacOS High Sierra disk without downloading it from the Apple store.

Using your Apple ID, create a free developer account and download the installer from https://developer.apple.com/download/

I certainly would not be installing a copy of macOS that wasn't downloaded from Apple